# notifyItemRemoved() not animating the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have implemented recycler view in fragment after longclick on an item i show a dialog and by selecting remove item i am removing it the problem i am facing is that by calling notifyItemRemoved() it is not aniamting the recycler as it should be 
but i am calling notifyItemRemoved() in a thread after completion of some background work please guide what i am doing wrong 
this is my 
Adapter Class

```
    public class SavedAlbumAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SavedAlbumAdapter2.ItemViewHolder> {


    private final GlideRequest<Drawable> request;

    private ArrayList<AlbumLocalObj> itemModels;
    private static final int LIST_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int GRID_ITEM = 1;
    private ClickListener mListener;
    private LocalPreferences localPreferences;


    public SavedAlbumAdapter2(Activity context, ArrayList<AlbumLocalObj> values, ClickListener clickListener) {
        itemModels = values;
        this.mListener = clickListener;
        localPreferences = new LocalPreferences(context);

        int reqWidth = ((HomeActivity) context).screenWidth / 2;
        request = GlideApp.with(context)
                .asDrawable()
                .centerCrop()
                .override(reqWidth, reqWidth)
                .transition(withNoTransition());


    }


    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        if (viewType == LIST_ITEM) {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_gallery2, parent, false);
        } else {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_gallery, parent, false);
        }
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AlbumLocalObj model = itemModels.get(position);

        holder.img_label.setText(model.getName());
        holder.tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(model.getCount()));
        initializeViews(model, holder, position);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (localPreferences.isGridViewEnabled()) {
            return GRID_ITEM;
        } else {
            return LIST_ITEM;
        }
    }

    private void initializeViews(AlbumLocalObj model, final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {


        if (model.getMediaFileObject() == null)
            holder.gallery_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_empty_fol);

        else {
            request.load(model.getMediaFileObject()).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.i("glide_action", "failure");
                    clearResource((MediaFileObject) model);

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    clearResource((MediaFileObject) model);
                    Log.i("glide_action", "success");
                    return false;
                }
            })

                    .into(holder.gallery_img);


        }


    }


    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int piecesAtPos);

        void onItemLongClick(View view, int piecesAtPos);

    }

    private void clearResource(MediaFileObject item) {
        try {

            if (item.getInputStream() != null) {
                Log.i("resource", "clear");
                item.getInputStream().close();
                item.setInputStream(null);
                //Log.i("closing_str", pos + "");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemModels.size();
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        SquarImageView gallery_img;
        TextView img_label;
        TextView tv_count;
        ImageButton info;
        private ClickListener mListener;


        ItemViewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            gallery_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            info = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info);
            img_label = itemView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            tv_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.count);

            this.mListener = listener;
            info.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            mListener.onItemLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my fragment method from which i am deleting an item(Album) i am calling this method onItemClick ( Dialog option (Delete))

```
private void deleteAlbum(final int selectedAlbum) {

if (list.get(selectedAlbum).getCount() == 0) {
    //return true if recycle bin contain some files check db function
    if (localDatabase.deleteAlbum(list.get(selectedAlbum).getId()))
        showRecycleBinContainSomeFiles();
    updateAlbumRecord();

    return;
}
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int progress = 0;
        ArrayList<MediaFileObject> selection = localDatabase.getAllMediaObjectsOfID(list.get(selectedAlbum).getId());

        for (MediaFileObject obj : selection) {
            if (searializeableTasks.isCancelled())
                break;
            localDatabase.deleteMediaObject(obj);
            progress++;
            if (searializeableTasks.isCancelled())
                sendProgressToHandle(-101);
            else
                sendProgressToHandle(progress);
        }

        if (!searializeableTasks.isCancelled()) {
            localDatabase.deleteAlbum(list.get(selectedAlbum).getId());
            list.remove(selectedAlbum);
            Log.e("selectedAlbum", selectedAlbum + "");
        }

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                savedAlbumAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedAlbum);
                savedAlbumAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(selectedAlbum, list.size());
                Log.e("sizes",list.size()+""+savedAlbumAdapter.getItemCount());
                ///savedAlbumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //updateAlbumRecord();

            }
        });


    }
};


searializeableTasks.startTasks(localDatabase.getAllMediaObjectsOfID(list.get(selectedAlbum).getId()).size(), runnable);
}
```

and if i put this line `list.remove(selectedAlbum);`
 in handler post just before `savedAlbumAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedAlbum);`
 it remove the very next item to it and when i restart the app that next item that was deleted come back its very weird please help what i am doing wrong

and please guide if any enhancement can be done Thanks :)

Comment: Where are you deleting selectedAlbum item from itemModels because of which  it mite be coming back.

Comment: no its not coming the very next item is also removed form the list if  i put this line list.remove(selectedAlbum);
in handler post just before savedAlbumAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedAlbum);
but when i come back its present there 
and animation is also not working (default remove/add anim)

Comment: What i meant are you removing object from ArrayList<AlbumLocalObj> itemModels of SavedAlbumAdapter2 ?

Comment: no i am deleting from my fragment's list  list.remove(index)

Comment: May be that is the issue than delete from itemModels array also to refelect changes. As recycler uses that data model to show list